# Perl PAR PP - Don't work /tmp/par-726f6f74/inc/lib/Mojo/resources/html_entities.txt

Tags: perl, mojo, perl-packager

I've been using pp

https://metacpan.org/pod/pp

A while ago!

However when hiring another hosting, when I run the pp command the scripts do not run on the server

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Perl v 5.32.1

Command using pp, host old

```
$ pp -x -c name.pl
```

When running

```
./a.out

Unable to open html entities file (/tmp/par-726f6f74/cache-78cdefedff4d2afddea0035addc3b570c8f0bfd5/inc/lib/Mojo/resources/html_entities.txt): No such file or directory at script / name.pl line 13.
Compilation failed in require at script / name.pl line 13.
BEGIN failed - compilation aborted at script / name.pl line 13.
```

And when I run `./name.pl` it runs normally.

Any suggestion?

name.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib ("$Bin");

use DBI;
use Number::Format;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use File::Basename;
use Mojo::Util qw(b64_encode b64_decode url_escape url_unescape);
use Mojo::JSON qw(decode_json encode_json);
use Image::ExifTool;
use LWP;


print "Test Mojo";
```

This same command works normally in version 5.28 on another server/hosting

Comment: What is the `use lib ("$Bin")` for ? Have you installed the modules locally?

Comment: I can reproduce this error on Ubuntu 21.04, perl version 5.32, [here](https://pastebin.com/dE3kZyHV) is minimal version that produces the error

Comment: The module was installed using ROOT

sudo cpan Mojo

I just created the folder: ./Mojo/resources/
containing the file: html_entities.txt

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/rschupp/PAR-Packer/issues/44)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the file `html_entities.txt` to the archive.
The following seems to work for me:

- Find the location of the file:

  ```
  $ perl -MMojo::Util -MFile::Basename=dirname -E '$fn = (dirname $INC{"Mojo/Util.pm"}) . "/resources/html_entities.txt"; say $fn'
  /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/Mojo/resources/html_entities.txt
  ```
- Copy the file to a local directory:

  ```
  $ mkdir -p ./lib/Mojo/resources/
  $ cp /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/Mojo/resources/html_entities.txt ./lib/Mojo/resources/
  ```
- Add the file to the archive

  ```
  $ pp -x -c -a lib/Mojo/resources/html_entities.txt name.pl
  ```

Comment: [https://github.com/rschupp/PAR-Packer/issues/44](https://github.com/rschupp/PAR-Packer/issues/44)

`cpanm git://github.com/rschupp/Module-ScanDeps.git`

100% solved

pp -x -c name.pl